# CSS - How do I prevent content div from overlapping on a fixed pos left-menu, IF the user resizes the browser and scrolls horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Here's an image to clarify a little

[image]

EDIT -- working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YE7ZZ/

I couldn't get a working js fiddle to recreate my problem, which exists on a site I'm developing for work so I can't just link the website yet either. I can paste some of my code, but let me explain first:

- I have a fixed pos left menu
- I have a content section that should always be positioned in the center of the remaining area not occupied by the left menu (so it is not positioned true center of the page, but rather shifted right because of the existence of the left menu).

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('../images/Imagine/bg_image44.png');
    background-attachment:fixed;
} 

#top {

}

#left {
    position:fixed;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:pink;
    width:250px;
}
#positioner {
    margin-left:250px;
    width:auto;
    background:grey;
}
#content {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:700px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left">menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br />menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br />menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br />menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br />menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br />menu item~~~~~<br /><br /><br /></div>
    <div id="positioner">
        <div id="content">asdf<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

            asdf<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            asdf<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            asdf<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate help so much. I had this issue 1.5 months ago and couldn't fix it, and figured it was such an edge-case it wouldn't matter, but long story short, now it does :P Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You've made a lot of effort posting your question but the HTML code you posted is insufficient to recreate your premise. You should make it more realistic, update your question and ideally provide a working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you're looking for implementing a grid based view. Look into using Twitter-Bootstrap grid system, it helped me a lot with my own project. There are a lot of others but I haven't used them personally

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle, hopefully it will be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/jKjRR/ The main issue is, I want the orange section to position in the CENTER of the whitespace, pretending that the left menu space cant be counted in the calculation. edit -- kind of really hard to see (IMO, unless you're amazing at CSS and can 'get' what i'm trying to show!) whats going on in the fiddle because the view space is so limited, and this is an issue about resizing windows thru the 800-1200px range

Comment: This surely calls for media queries to change the width of the content div

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the OP that clearly illustrates the main problem I'm having. How can I prevent the center from overlapping onto the left? Is a jq onscroll event needed to adjust margins dynamically perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Example with media queries and %-based main content width

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xswjt)

```
.content {
  width:35%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {

  .content {width:43%;}
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {

  .content {width:55%;}
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {

  .content {width:60%;}
}

@media (min-width: 1180px) {

  .content {width:65%;}
}
```